# Большое ли преимущество использования IN вместо множества OR в sql?

Tags: sql

На примере

```
select *
from table
where property in ('a','b','c')
```

или

```
select *
from table
where property='a' or property='b' or property='c'
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Если говорить про абстрактный SQL - никакой разницы нет. Есть много способов попросить достать одни и те же данные. Впрочем, с точки зрения читаемости человеком `in` явно выигрывает из-за компактности.

А если рассматривать конкретные реализации - то различия могут быть. Например, мой локальный `postgresql` строит разные планы:

```
melkij=> explain select * from bigtable where id = 1 or id = 3 or id=4;
                                    QUERY PLAN                                    
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Bitmap Heap Scan on bigtable  (cost=13.34..25.34 rows=3 width=12)
   Recheck Cond: ((id = 1) OR (id = 3) OR (id = 4))
   ->  BitmapOr  (cost=13.34..13.34 rows=3 width=0)
         ->  Bitmap Index Scan on bigtable_pkey  (cost=0.00..4.45 rows=1 width=0)
               Index Cond: (id = 1)
         ->  Bitmap Index Scan on bigtable_pkey  (cost=0.00..4.45 rows=1 width=0)
               Index Cond: (id = 3)
         ->  Bitmap Index Scan on bigtable_pkey  (cost=0.00..4.45 rows=1 width=0)
               Index Cond: (id = 4)

melkij=> explain select * from bigtable where id in (1,3,4);
                                   QUERY PLAN                                   
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Index Scan using bigtable_pkey on bigtable  (cost=0.44..17.37 rows=3 width=12)
   Index Cond: (id = ANY ('{1,3,4}'::integer[]))
```

Как можно заметить, `in` был переписан в другую форму и оценён дешевле, чем несколько эквивалентных `or`

Какие-то другие СУБД может быть переписывают оба запроса в идентичное представление, или же переписывают `in` в группу `or`. Вопросы производительности необходимо рассматривать только в рамках какой-то конкретной реализации.

Answer (score 5):

В дополнение к сказанному @Мелкий.

`MS SQL Server` на оба запроса генерирует абсолютно одинаковые планы не зависимо от наличия индекса.

В `MySQL`, согласно [документации](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in) `in` использует бинарный поиск, т.е. теоретически должен быть быстрее, чем `or`. На практике оказывается, что при наличии индекса разницы почти нет, а при отсутствии `in` работает примерно на 30% [быстрее](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3074731/8461588).